# $G = S_7$, $a=(2,5,7)$, $b=(5,7)(4,3,1,6)$, $H = \langle a, b \rangle$, and let $K=\langle b \rangle$. Is K normal in H?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups, permutation-cycles

$K$ is normal in $H$ if $\forall h \in H, hKh^{-1}\subseteq K$. Alternatively you can check if the right cosets equal the left cosets. I was wondering if there is an easier way of doing this than doing out the computations.

Is there anyother way of checking if the subgroup $K$ is normal than  writing out the elements of $H$ and calculating $hKh^{-1}$ to see if it is a subgroup of $K$.

Comment: I think it suffices to show that $aba^{-1}\in K$.

Comment: Or not, as the case may  be.

Comment: It isn't normal, since $aba^{-1}$ sends $5\to 2$, which clearly can't happen in an element of $K$. If $aba^{-1}$ was in $K$, $K$ would be normal since all other elements are combinations of $a,b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compute: $aba^{-1}=(257)(57)(4316)(275)=(1643)(27)$.  But, nothing in $K$ moves $2$.  Thus $aba^{-1}\not\in K$ and $K$ isn't normal.

Comment: Great answer thank you